# Count ChildElements of the same name, inside an XML Element, with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file that looks like this -

```
<SST_SignageCompConfig>
  <Items>
    <Item>
      <Index>0</Index>
      <Type>1</Type>
      <Duration>7</Duration>
      <Name>Branding-Colours-for-business.jpg</Name>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Index>1</Index>
      <Type>1</Type>
      <Duration>7</Duration>
      <Name>Flower of Life Meditation - Copy.png</Name>
    </Item>
</Items>
</SST_SignageCompConfig>
```

I need to count how many `Item` Elements there are within the `Items` Element. 

**ie** how many images there are.

I'm using `XDocument`, so my XML file is loaded like this -

```
string configurationPath = System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\\SST Software\\DSS\\Compilations\\" + compName + @"\\Comp.cfg");
XDocument filedoc = XDocument.Load(configurationPath);
```

I've tried numerous variations of the following, with all returning a `null object reference exception`

```
foreach (var item in filedoc.Element("SST_SignageCompConfig").Element("Items").Element("Item").Nodes())
{
    string name = filedoc.Element("SST_SignageCompConfig").Element("Items").Element("Item").Attribute("Name").ToString();
    files.Append(name + "|");
}
```

I've found countless examples of how to count how many **different** child elements are within an element, but I need to know how many instances of the **same** element exist. 


Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried adding in a try catch to handle elements which do not have a name?

Comment: You've said you're trying to find the count, but your code is collecting the names - what exactly is your required output?

Comment: The XML is generated programmatically from another method with extensive error handling, so an `Item` element will always have a `name` attribute :)

Comment: Your main problem is there is no `name` attribute, it's a `Name` *element*.

Comment: @CharlesMager **That** is a very very good point. Oh the shame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all names like so:

```
var names = from item in filedoc.Descendants("Item")
            select (string)item.Element("Name");
```

Or without the query syntax:

```
var names = filedoc.Descendants("Item").Elements("Name").Select(e => e.Value);
```

You can get only unique names by:

```
var uniqueNames = names.Distinct();
```

Comment: Clean and simple - perfect! :)

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. Try finding out exactly *which* invocation is giving you the NullReferenceException. My guess is that it's the attempt to find:

```
.Element("SST_SignageCompConfig")
```

Which is your root. Try the following instead:

```
// note the difference between .Element and .Elements
var count = filedoc.Root.Element("Items").Elements("Item").Count();
```

You could also use XPath to help you nail down the navigation within your XDocument:

```
// returns the current top level element
var element = filedoc.Root.XPathSelectElement(".");

// If the returned element is "SST_SignageCompConfig", then:
var nextElement = filedoc.Root.XPathSelectElement("./Items")

// If the "." element is *not* "SST_SignageCompConfig", then try and locate where in your XML document that node is. 
// You can navigate up with .Parent and down with .Element(s)
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var nav = fileDoc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator navShape = nav.Select("/SST_SignageCompConfig/Items");
navShape.MoveNext()
var count = navShape.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your xml has only one `Items` element, this should do the trick:

```
filedoc.Descendants("Item")
    .GroupBy(e => e.Element("Name")!=null? e.Element("Name").Value:String.Empty)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Name = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because "Name" is an element and not an attribute of your xml structure.

can you try replacing this?

```
string name = filedoc.Element("SST_SignageCompConfig").Element("Items").Element("Item").Element("Name").ToString();
```